# Optional arguments in plain TeX

Tags: macros, plain-tex

This is a turnstile with and without a subscript

```
\def\stile{{|\kern-.225em-}}

\def\sstile#1{{|\kern-.225em-}_{\rm #1}}

$$\stile \alpha$$

$$\sstile{K} \alpha$$

\bye
```

It would be nice to have just one command and be able to type either
`\stile \alpha` or `\stile[K] \alpha`.  How is that done?

[image]

Comment: You can look into `latex.ltx` how `\newcommand` is defined in order to make your `Plain` version of that

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Look ahead for the `[`:

```
\def\stile{\futurelet\next\dostile}
\def\dostile{%
  \mathrel{|\mkern-4mu{-}}
  \ifx[\next %]
    \expandafter\dostileopt
  \fi
}
\def\dostileopt[#1]{_{\rm #1}}

$\stile \alpha$

$\stile[K] \alpha$

\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

You could use the plain compatible `eplain` macros:

[image]

```
\input eplain

\catcode`\@=11

\def\stile{\@getoptionalarg\xstile}

\def\xstile{{|\kern-.225em-}%
    \ifx\@optionalarg\empty\else_{\rm\@optionalarg}\fi}

\catcode`\@=12

$$\stile \alpha$$

$$\stile[K] \alpha$$

\bye
```

Answer (score 5):

With a primitive implementation of `\@ifnextchar` (taking the one from `latex.ltx` would be better, I guess):

```
\catcode`\@=11
\long\def\@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}%
\long\def\@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}%
\long\def\@ifnextchar#1#2#3#4{%
  \ifx#1#4%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {#2}{#3}#4}%
\def\stile{\@ifnextchar[{\stile@i}{\stile@ii}}%
\def\stile@i[#1]{{|\kern-.225em-}_{\rm #1}}%
\def\stile@ii{{|\kern-.225em-}}%
\catcode`\@=12

$$\stile \alpha$$

$$\stile[K] \alpha$$

\bye
```

A more stable version of `\@ifnextchar` (similar to the one of `latex.ltx` but not the same):

```
\long\def\@ifnextchar#1#2#3{%
  \let\@tmpa=#1%
  \def\@tmpb{#2}%
  \def\@tmpc{#3}%
  \futurelet\@future\@ifnextchar@i}%
\def\@ifnextchar@i{%
  \ifx\@tmpa\@future%
    \expandafter\@tmpb
  \else
    \expandafter\@tmpc
  \fi}%
```

Comment: The problem with this is that `\stile{[}K]` works like this, or may be `\stile {[A/B] \over C}` will give problems.

Comment: @Manuel as I said, it's a primitive implementation.

Comment: A primitive definition of `\ifnextchar` (that does not skip spaces) could be easily done with `\futurelet` like egreg. I just wanted to note that, if someone knows what (s)he's doing (s)he can use this version.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that you tagged this `{plain-tex}`, but this really is an instance in which the use of LaTeX, with the [turnstile](https://ctan.org/pkg/turnstile) package, would be of considerable help.

You could then simply use, `$\sststile{\mathrm{K}}{} \alpha$`. This package would also improve the overall typesetting quality of your turnstiles (refer to the below image, from the [`turnstile` article](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/turnstile/turnstile-en/turnstile_article.pdf)), and provide a myriad of additional options.

[image: Comparison of turnstile subscript typography]